# Saving JSON file in Azure Storage Data Lake ended up with NUL (Ascii 0) characters and spaces

Tags: azure, spring-boot, azure-data-lake, jackson-databind, azure-data-lake-gen2

We are creating json file in Azure Data Lake Gen2 from java application. File write success but content is encoded with one liner of NUL (Ascii 0) characters. This is happening intermittently

**Code snippet:**

```
DataLakeServiceClientBuilder builder = new DataLakeServiceClientBuilder();
builder.credential(...);
builder.endpoint(...);

DataLakeServiceClient dataLakeServiceClient = builder.buildClient();
DataLakeFileSystemClient fileSystemClient = dataLakeServiceClient.getFileSystemClient(<fileSystemName>);

DataLakeDirectoryClient directoryClient = fileSystemClient.getDirectoryClient(<directoryName>)
                    .getSubdirectoryClient(<subDirectoryName>).getSubdirectoryClient(<subDirectoryName>);

DataLakeFileClient fileClient = directoryClient.createFile("data_lake_file.json");

File file = new File("local_file.json");

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
objectMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValue(file, <java object>);

InputStream targetStream = new FileInputStream(file);
String datalakePath = fileClient.getFilePath();
long fileSize = file.length();
fileClient.append(targetStream, 0, fileSize);
fileClient.flush(fileSize);
```

Comment: I have encountered similar situation, but it does not affect my reading. Can you show the code?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Updated question with code snippet. please have a look

Comment: "but content is encoded with one liner of NUL (Ascii 0) characters"
Are you saying the file contains only nulls? Or that there is a null at the end?